# Get address of cell copied from excel via clipboard

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

How to get the Address of the cells copied from excel via clipboard in Vb.net ?

In Vb6 exe by using
Clipboard.GetText(vbCFLink)
Will able to to get Output  as

> Excel|[excel path]Sheet1!R48C2:R57C3

How to get the Range of cell copied in vb.net.
In vb.net and vb6 existing methods.

```
VB6                 VB.NET

vbCFBitmap       System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap

vbCFDIB          System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.DIB

vbCFEMetafile    System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile
 
vbCFFiles        System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop

vbCFMetafile     System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.MetafilePict

vbCFPalette      System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Palette

vbCFRTF          System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Rtf

vbCFText         System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text
```

As per [this](https://www.visualbasicplanet.info/upgrading-visual-basic/upgrading-the-clipboard-object.html) link For vbCFLink -    No equivalent in vb.net

I created a VB6 ocx/dll and used it to get the same result in VB.net appliation but this not feasible for production currently.

Is there any other method to get the Address range of the cells copied from excel via clipboard in Vb.net?

Comment: When you get the ClipBoard content of an Excel copy, you get multiple formats. Among these, the XML representation of the section (`XML Spreadsheet` format), simple text format and Unicode Text representation (TAB separated), the CSV representation (`Csv` format), the RTF representation (`Rich Text Format` format), HTML (`HTML Format` format), a Bitmap that portraits the section of the Worksheet copied, also in `BIFF12`, `BIFF8`, `BIFF5`, `Enhanced MetaFile`, `MetaFilePict` and `DataInterchangeFormat` formats, the `Link Source` and `LinkSource Descriptor` formats etc.

Comment: It also includes the Bitmaps of the images embedded in the Worksheet. The images are saved in the current User's `Temp` folder, The paths to these images are provided as URIs (i.e., as `file://[path]/[file]`

Comment: I know about the these different formats of clipboard. But how to get the "address of cell" copied from excel via clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still do this with `Clipboard.GetData()`, you just have to read the stream yourself:

```
Using reader = New StreamReader(CType(Clipboard.GetData("Link"), Stream))
    str = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace(vbNullChar, "|"c)
End Using
```

(Excuse my VB, it's auto translated from C# so may be a little funny.)

You can examine the current clipboard and all it's formats using [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html) handy utility from Nirsoft, and use `GetData()` to retreive them.

And with edits suggested by @dr.null, you can create a function to replicate the `GetText` function:

```
Function GetTextFromClipboard(type As String) As String
    If Not Clipboard.ContainsData(type) Then Return String.Empty
    Dim stream = TryCast(Clipboard.GetData(type), Stream)
    If stream Is Nothing Then Return String.Empty
    Using reader = New StreamReader(stream)
        Return reader.ReadToEnd().TrimEnd(ControlChars.NullChar).Replace(ControlChars.NullChar, "|"c)
    End Using
End Function
```

And use it for excel links:

```
Var str = GetTextFromClipboard("Link")
```